# Excel Sophisticated Sort - Return low/high values

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort data imported from a csv file.  The data comes in like such:

```
Columns
 A | B
--------
t1 | 1
t3 | 9
t1 | 2
t2 | 5
t1 | 1
t3 | 13
t1 | 3
t3 | 11
t2 | 4
t2 | 7
t3 | 10
t3 | 10
```

and i want output similar to this:

```
    Columns
 D  |  E  |  F
----------------
t1  |  1  |  3
t2  |  4  |  7
t3  |  9  |  13
```

Explanation: Basically what I need to do is find the lowest and highest values from column B for each different value in column A, and list them neatly as shown in the second example.

Ive worked with VBA before, so if this would have to be done via VBA thats fine.  Im just at a loss as to how to accomplish this task.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, if would make the task simpler, its fine if i have to manually sort the data alphabetically based on col A (thus putting same values together)

Comment: This is a perfect task for a Pivot Table

Comment: What version of Excel are you using - the details of setting up a Pivot are a little different in the different versions

Comment: 2007, same as RocketDonkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @chrisneilsen that a Pivot Table is the best way to go. If you are set on using formulas, you can try using the following (both entered as arrays - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

In cell `E1`, which will represent the minimum value:

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$12=D1,1,MAX($B$1:$B$12)+1)*$B$1:$B$12)
```

And in cell `F1`, which will represent the maximum value:

```
=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$12=D1,1,MIN($B$1:$B$12)-1)*$B$1:$B$12)
```

The general idea is that check to see which values in column `A` are equal to your target value (column `D`). The result will be an array of `1`'s where there is a match, and using `MIN` as an example, the maximum of the column + 1. This is done because we want to set this equal to a value that can't possibly be attained in your current setup, so the maximum value + 1 will ensure that `MIN` will return a value that is legitimate.

[image]

Here is a Pivot Table using Excel 2007. To create, add column headers to your data, select your data and then in the Ribbon click `Insert -> Pivot Table`. In the dialog box, you decide where you want to put it (it is commonly put in a New Worksheet, so you can leave the default if you want - I left it in the same worksheet for illustration purposes). From there, you can arrange it by dragging each field so it matches the pictures. For the `Max/Min` fields, just drag the `Value` field into the `Values` section twice. Then, in the actual Pivot Table, you can right-click on one of the values in the column and select `Summarize Data By -> Min` to summarize by the minimum value for each key:

[image]

Comment: Im not set on any particular way, if you think the better/more elegant way would be a Pivot Table, Im willing to try it if your willing to tell me how as Ive never used one lol

Comment: also, to clarify, if i use the solution presented in this answer, i would manually enter the values in col D? (t1, t2, t3 etc for example?)

Comment: @DEFSoftwareSolutions Yes, forgot to mention that you need to add those values manually (you can select the entire range, copy and paste into column `D`, and then use `Data -> Remove Duplicates` to get the unique values. I'll put in a Pivot Table example as well.

Comment: Awesome, i appreciate the help.  I will mark this as answer, and will review Pivot Table in a bit.  I have to run to the store right quick to get medicine for my daughter.  I will return in a bit, thanks again.  Cant wait to see how the Pivot Table works

Comment: @DEFSoftwareSolutions No problem at all - Pivot Tables are great resources for summarizing data (and much more dynamic than formulas). You'll learn to love them :)

Comment: This is an amazing answer.  One question before i try the pivot table, if do a pivot table, will i be able to copy/paste the result chart elsewhere? (will actually end up putting into a txt file in notepad)

Comment: @DEFSoftwareSolutions Ha, thanks :) And to answer your question, yes - you can just copy the values you want and paste where you want it to go. However one thing to note is that when you start to get into 'nested' fields' (more than one `Row` value in the Pivot setup), the displayed results won't have all keys on each row. That probably doesn't make sense, but try adding additional values into the `Row Values` field and see what happens.

Comment: pivot table works nice, tho curious how to sort in a custom manner, not just alphabetical.  Also, formulas above did not work for me

Comment: nvm, figured out how to set to drag to manually reorder pivot table

Comment: @DEFSoftwareSolutions You're a quick study :) Good luck with everything.

Comment: thanks again man, LOVE the Pivot Table, gunna hafta remember this one lol.  Made even easier by sorting A --> Z on min col. (sorting numerically that way makes the "Key" terms from ur example arrange the way supposed to

Comment: @DEFSoftwareSolutions Sweet, happy to hear it is working - enjoy the Pivoting :)